# HVAC and water heater help

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, furnace, water-heater, ventilation

I need help deciding what to do in my home. We have a small closet upstairs that contains our furnace and water heater. The air conditioner currently installed is not working and has been turned off until a new unit has been affixed to the roof. My biggest concern about the whole situation is that when I opened the water heater closet, I was met with a heat wave coming from an exhaust port that vents directly to the roof. The upstairs is incredibly hard to keep cool even with in wall units. Some days it reaches 90 degrees F in the hallway. We currently do not have the water heater in use if that makes any difference. I was wondering if I could plug this vent temporarily until we get a new ac unit installed? It's really the only thing that makes the house warm and I'd really like to plug it so we can cool down more efficiently. Any advice or questions is appreciated. Thanks. Attached is a picture of said water heater closet with the vent on the right side. [image: waterheatercloset]

Comment: Despite good isolation the water heater will emit heat. Your best choice is to ventilate that room.

Comment: I do not see exhaust Fan. Is it on the roof ? or is it a passive exaust (no fan)

Comment: By Furnace do you mean the AC heat exchanger with fan or actual furnace.

Comment: There is no fan on the vent. It is passive

Comment: The hot air is coming from that metal vent

Comment: What about installing a ventilator is that possible

Comment: it could be it is coming from your attic

Comment: I don't believe that larger duct on the right side of the pic is for exhaust, I believe it's probably for combustion air intake.   to answer your question, yes, you can tape it off as long as the WH and furnace are not in use.

Comment: Was that vent previously connected to anything? Was it part of the AC ducting in any way? If not, I think George is correct that it may be for bringing combustion air into the closet. It seems like it's really oversized for that, though. Specifying the brand/model of the water heater and furnace would help people determine how much air you need. If it is make-up air, then no, you can't block it off, presuming you're still making hot water for the house, even in the summer.